Did my contractor screw up flat roof insulation?
I'm nearing completion on a new build, and my contractor has been making some field changes that are not 100% reflected in the architectural plans. Some of this has been necessary, but I'm starting to uncover a number of things related to the roof that are not as intended.
We have a 1:12 roof slope and unvented "attic" (if you can call it that). The sub-roof / ceiling structure was framed as 2x10s and it contains a host of stuff, including HVAC ducts, romex, in-ceiling speaker boxes, recessed lights, fire sprinklers, and supply lines for radiant floor heating.
The roof was then filled with open cell spray foam (9.5-inch depth, I'm told, based on the 2x10 framing). But in some places where there is HVAC ducts or speaker boxes, obviously it can't be 9.5 inches of insulation in those spots.
The original architect spec calls for minimum of R-30 insulation, with spray foam and then rigid insulation on top. CURRENTLY there is is no rigid board - just the open cell spray foam and then plywood on top of that.
We were originally supposed to have a standing seam metal roof put on, but because of low slope and some shenanigans on my contractor's part, that looks unlikely, so I'm actively exploring PVC & TPO options instead.
QUESTION: I want to make sure that my roof "attic" is properly insulated so I don't end up with a dew point or condensation in the middle of the open cell spray foam which will rot things from the inside out.
How do I ensure that the insulation is sufficient and that I don't need to add additional rigid or other insulation on top before putting on my roof?
For reference, we're in Northern California. We get lots of rain, but almost no frost. Temperature extremes range from ~32-33 F in the coldest parts of winter to 102+ F at peak summer.
Photos of the roof framing are below. Underneath (on the inside of the house) is plywood and then 1x4 cedar T&G (1/4 inch cedar on a plywood backing)
Image link: https://imgur.com/a/low-slope-roof-insulation-OHNxibk



what is your air barrier?  do you have poly inside before drywall ?

Currently no air barrier (yet). There will be a waterproof membrane put down either under the metal roof, or as the PVC/TPO, from what I understand. I'm trying to figure out what else I might need to add on top of the framing & spray foam. On the interior of the house (under attic space) there's 9/8ths (1 and 1/8) plywood and then 1x4 cedar planks.
